# Php and XML for a newbie

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have this simple `xml` file :

```
<iPhone> 
  <anEvent>
    <data1>some Data</data1>
    <data2>Some data here </data2>
  </anEvent>

  <anEvent>
    <data1>some Data</data1>
    <data2>Some data here </data2>
  </anEvent>

</iPhone>
```

I need to get  remove it from this file and write it to another file.

To get the `<anEvent>` i want, i do (i just want to transfer only one anEvent) :

```
$dom = new DomDocument(); 
$dom->load('myFile.xml');
$myData = $dom->getElementsByTagName('anEvent')->item(0);
```

I get my  at index 0 it's cool. 
In order to remove it I simply use :

```
$customRequete->parentNode->removeChild($myData);   
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save("myFile.xml");
```

It works, that's cool. 
The problem is when I want to write the `<anEvent>` to another file. 
I know how to write to XML but not using DOM DOCUMENT :

```
$myNewFile = simplexml_load_file("myNewFile.xml");
$event = $myNewFile->addChild('anEvent'); 
$data1 = $event->addChild('data1','someData'); 
$data2 = $event->addChild('data2','some data here');
```

I was wondering if I could use `$myData` from my `$dom` in order to write something like :

```
$myNewFile -> addChild($myData); 
$myNewFile->save();
```

Or do I need to loop into `$myData` to get the node values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move nodes from a document to another, you have to import them, using the [`importNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) method on the new created `DOMDocument`. The latter parameter allows you to recursively import every node child.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to copy the file you could use PHP's [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DOMDocument::importNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php).  The example on that page should be what you need.